# Why Google Apps have TikTok APIs and Libraries?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, google

I'm new to Android app development, but a privacy Enthusiast who looks into the Activity's of Apps to see what kind of **tracking** does the specific apps use. And while doing so, I came across, **TikTok's APIs** and **Libraries** that are related to Account and all. And I've a very little amount of knowledge about that.
**BELOW IMAGE:** Receivers that Google App has. [App is Warden]
[image: This is image of Receivers that Google App has.]

I've turned off those TikTok's things(I'm not sure whether they're libraries or APIs or any other and sorry for that).

I've searched the internet and got no results that are related to my query but related to usage of TikTok's APIs.

Editing's are welcome. Waiting for **knowledge** about these.:)

Comment: Related on Stack Overflow: [Does anyone know the function of this Android class? “com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.db”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64931177/2821954). Google is known to use weird/"unique" package names (there were some questions related on here, but I currently couldn't find them), and it's just a coincidence that there's TikTok app now.

Comment: Here, in India, TikTok is banned months back stating "Privacy Concerns" by the Government. And I was somewhat amazed to see every Google Apps using the the content from the banned app...

Comment: Wow, that sounds weird. Just read that tweet by Pratik on twitter. Google is weirdmost of the times!

Answer (score 2):

According to the Google Xander‌ (which is "Gold Product Expert") on the [support](https://support.google.com/android/thread/197299336?msgid=198126219):

> Tiktok is an internal component in Google used by many apps, it was written and named like that before the social network existed and is absolutely unrelated.